# Hindi language and sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, hindi

How can I use sublime text with the Hindi language? I just want to copy and paste the word: " इटली " in the editor, but It returns me the following text instead:
[image]

How to remove that circle?

Comment: If you found any solution then please share it.

Comment: I have Sublime Text 3.2.2 and it shows the text correctly after I save the file with .txt extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove that circle.But that won't cause a problem. If you are going to show it in a web-page it will be shown normally. 
Other solution is to use notepad instead. 
[image]